# Overlay scene not showing

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have 2 scenes: One main scene with a button, and another scene with only 1 text.

**button action in Main Scene:**

```
local options =
{
    effect = "fade",
    time = 400,
    params =
    {
        sample_var = "anything",
        custom = "you want",
        data = "here"
    }
}
storyboard.showOverlay("inventory", options)
```

**The Overlay Scene:**

```
local storyboard = require("storyboard")
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    local title = display.newText("Inventory", 20, 20, native.systemFont, 16)
    title:setTextColor(255,0,0)
    group:insert(title)
end

function scene:enterScene( event )
    print("enterScene")
end

function scene:exitScene( event )
    print("exitScene")
end

function scene:destroyScene( event )
    print("destroyScene")
end

scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

return scene
```

After pressed the "button", nothing happens (no error). Main Scene is still active & accessible. According to official [documentation](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/04/27/scene-overlays-and-parameter-passing/), a scene should appear after pressing the button.

What did I miss?

Note: Both scene has similar structure (using Storyboard), and button as main scene is created with the following codes:

```
function scene:createScene( event )
  btnInventory = display.newImage("images/btn_right.png", 320, 600)
  btnInventory:addEventListener("tap", openInventory)
end
```

where `openInventory` is the first code listing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up I found out that the Ceramic Tile Map covers everything (it's just like on topmost layer). If the map is removed, the overlay works fine.

p.s. I found that `Director` module is easier to use than Storyboard. I switched to it.

Answer (score 0):

Should work, I just tried it.

So perhaps you have a typo in the scene file name or is it in a sub-folder ?

If it's in a sub-folder you've got to call :

```
storyboard.showOverlay("mysubfolder.inventory", options)
```

Comment: I found that it's the Ceramic Tile Map covers everything.